# Label workspace with command in TFS

Tags: tfs

```
C:\Users\mif\.jenkins\jobs\Trunk_-_Nightly_Build\workspace>tf label /owner:tfs.service Samplelabelname

Error message: Please specify a label name.
```

what am I doing wrong? I want to label a whole workspace

Comment: did you check if you are using correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 C:\Users\mif\.jenkins\jobs\Trunk_-_Nightly_Build\workspace>tf label Samplelabelname /owner:tfs.service . /recursive
```

Taking a look into the help (tf label /?), you will see the order of the information and that labelname needs to be specified before the itemspec, which is mandatory!
In this case I set the itemspec to . which should be the actual folder and added the recursive flag, to include all subfolders.